# How to join tables in Mysql with empty table

Tags: mysql, join

I have four table like this:

companies (title, description)

company_users (company_id, user_id)

users (id, group_id)

user_profiles (user_id, fullname)

I want to list campaigns.

My code is this:

```
SELECT companies.*, user_profiles.fullname as company_contact
FROM companies
INNER JOIN company_users ON companies.id = company_users.company_id
INNER JOIN users ON company_users.user_id = users.id AND users.group_id=500
INNER JOIN user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id;
```

When i add a new campaign does not appear. Because company_id not in company_users.

How can i fix this?

Note: Eeach campaign must have only one user. This user's group_id is 500.

Thank You

Edit:

Tables:

```
companies
1   |   Test Company    |   Test Desciption
2   |   Test Company 2  |   Test Description 2



company_users
1   |   18  |   1
2   |   19  |   1

users
18  |   500     
19  |   900


user_profiles
18  |   18  |   Test Contact
19  |   19  |   Test User
```

LEFT JOIN Result:

```
1   Test Company    Test Description    Test Contact
1   Test Company    Test Description    NULL
2   Test Company 2  Test Description 2  NULL
```

INNER JOIN Result:

```
1   Test Company    Test Description    Test Contact
```

I need this:

```
1   Test Company    Test Description    Test Contact
1   Test Company 2  Test Description 2  NULL
```

Comment: user LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN this is basic SQL  this is good reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins

Comment: Nope this is not simple likely this. When i use LEFT, listed all companies with all users. I need only list companies that group_id eq 500. I updated my answer. Query results added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like we want **outer join** operations.

We can replace all occurrences of the keyword `INNER` with the keyword `LEFT`.

Then the query will return rows from `companies` even when no matching row is found in `company_users`.

**EDIT**

In response to question edit that provides additional information.

If we want to return every row in companies, along with the fullname of a single row from a related user (as shown in the desired resultset), we could use a correlate subquery in the SELECT list, rather than a join operation.

For example:

```
  SELECT c.*
       , ( SELECT p.fullname
             FROM company_users cu
             JOIN users ON u.id = cu.user_id AND u.group_id=500
             JOIN user_profiles p ON p.user_id = u.id 
            WHERE cu.company_id = c.id
            ORDER BY p.fullname ASC
            LIMIT 1
         ) AS company_contact
    FROM companies c
```

The subquery includes a reference to the `id` column in `companies`.  For each row returned from the outer query (each row from `companies`), the subquery in the SELECT list is executed, using the `id` value from the `companies` row,

If the subquery doesn't find a row to return, a NULL value is returned. The `LIMIT 1` clause ensures that we return at most one row (if the subquery returns more than one row, there will be an error returned.) The `ORDER BY` is included just to make the result more deterministic. That is, if the subquery happens to return more than one row, the `ORDER BY` will sort the rows, and the `LIMIT 1` will get the first of the sorted rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  When i use LEFT, listed all companies with all users. I need only list companies that group_id eq 500. I updated my answer. Query results added

Comment: I added an example query that makes use of a correlated subquery to return the `fullname` from the user_profiles table, instead of using join operations.